# Is there any web script to compress files on server?

Tags: server, ftp, compression, backups

Hey I was just looking for a script to compress all my files on my server through FTP or any other thing. I want to keep the compressed files as backup...
And i know that many hosts support it, but i'm using godaddy and there's a limit of 20MB on compressing. is there any script without any limit which i can run and compress all the files and download and keep as backup?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i think this might me what your looking for
http://www.phpmybackuppro.net/

I use this for sites that on cheap shared hosting. It's main feature is to backup MYSQL, this makes it easy to automate rather than going via a control panel. however it will also compress whole directories. it can save the backups to the server, send them to a remote FTP server or email them.